# Google Maps Android API v2 doesn't show up in my Developer's Console

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-android-api-1

The title pretty much says it all. I can enable **'Google Maps Android API'** in my console, but there's no **'Google Maps Android API v2'** for me to choose. Am I missing something?

[image]

After enabling **'Google Maps Android API'**, this is what I get in my console:

[image]

Comment: 2nd option click please.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya That's what I've been using, it's the v1 of the API.

Comment: v1 was deprecated and is not available anymore. The Google Maps Android API v2 is the only one available in developer console.

Comment: @xomena Even though it says 'v1' in my console?

Comment: I can see only Google Maps Android API in your screenshot, there is no v1 in the title.

Comment: Ah, you mean the usage report. It sounds like a mistake in developer console interface. Do you use maps from Google play services? If so, this is v2.

Comment: Definitely, something is weird with an interface. When I check Maps JavaScript API I can also see this v1, but the only existing version of Maps JavaScript API is v3: https://ibb.co/iWvsx6

Comment: It must be it, then. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the console is a bit different now. 
The name "**Google Maps Android API v2**" is no longer in use.

Check out this link if you want to quickly generate your google map api key after activating the service: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHxtO.jpg)